# Ruby Parsing Hash

Tags: ruby, arrays, parsing, hash

So I'm using a gem file to pull links from the front page of reddit. The gem function returns a hash containing *ALL* the links on the front page and all their info (# of comments, karma, author, date, link, ups, downs, etc). Below is a begging of the hash containg the information for the *FIRST* link on my front page:

> {"modhash"=>"ubekfji9tr491ba98806d33ec78693dc157579335eb1ab283b",
>   "children"=>[{"kind"=>"t3", "data"=>{"domain"=>"i.imgur.com",
>   "banned_by"=>nil, "media_embed"=>{}, "subreddit"=>"pics",
>   "selftext_html"=>nil, "selftext"=>"", "likes"=>nil,
>   "link_flair_text"=>nil, "id"=>"1dt29e", "clicked"=>false,
>   "title"=>"Our plumber in Italy put himself out there to ask us for
>   help on his English homework :) Hope he passes his finals!",
>   "media"=>nil, "score"=>3700, "approved_by"=>nil, "over_18"=>false,
>   "hidden"=>false,
>   "thumbnail"=>"http://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/Fdid4luCfXah0bQ7.jpg",
>   "subreddit_id"=>"t5_2qh0u", "edited"=>false,
>   "link_flair_css_class"=>nil, "author_flair_css_class"=>nil,
>   "downs"=>17890, "saved"=>false, "is_self"=>false,
>   "permalink"=>"/r/pics/comments/1dt29e/our_plumber_in_italy_put_himself_out_there_to_ask/",
>   "name"=>"t3_1dt29e", "created"=>1367893951.0,
>   "url"=>"https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWZRf.jpg", "author_flair_text"=>nil,
>   "author"=>"Junpha", "created_utc"=>1367865151.0, "distinguished"=>nil,
>   "num_comments"=>553, "num_reports"=>nil, "ups"=>21590}},

That ending `,` seperates the next link which looks like this:

> {"kind"=>"t3", "data"=>{"domain"=>"i.imgur.com", "banned_by"=>nil,
>   "media_embed"=>{}, "subreddit"=>"funny", "selftext_html"=>nil,
>   "selftext"=>"", "likes"=>nil, "link_flair_text"=>nil, "id"=>"1dt4xv",
>   "clicked"=>false, "title"=>"What a beautiful, majestic.... oops",
>   "media"=>nil, "score"=>2848, "approved_by"=>nil, "over_18"=>false,
>   "hidden"=>false,
>   "thumbnail"=>"http://a.thumbs.redditmedia.com/vkstE1PFr9iyYpux.jpg",
>   "subreddit_id"=>"t5_2qh33", "edited"=>false,
>   "link_flair_css_class"=>nil, "author_flair_css_class"=>nil,
>   "downs"=>8128, "saved"=>false, "is_self"=>false,
>   "permalink"=>"/r/funny/comments/1dt4xv/what_a_beautiful_majestic_oops/",
>   "name"=>"t3_1dt4xv", "created"=>1367895955.0,
>   "url"=>"https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzIqQ.gif", "author_flair_text"=>nil,
>   "author"=>"themisc", "created_utc"=>1367867155.0,
>   "distinguished"=>nil, "num_comments"=>279, "num_reports"=>nil,
>   "ups"=>10976}},

I basically need someway to parse each entry of this hash so that I can store all the relevant stuff into an array. Really, I just want to store the `"title"` and `"url"` parts into an array. I tried something like this:

```
@red.get_listing().each do |x['title']|
    puts x
end
```

But i realized this is a hash of a hash..so I'm kinda lost as to how to parse this.

Comment: If it's a hash, why would you need to parse it? You access inner haves the same way as outer hashes.

Comment: @DaveNewton i'm a total newb at ruby...lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
hash[:children].each do |child|
  puts child[:title]
  puts child[:url]
end
```

Does that help?

Comment: kind of...the problem now is that the returned value from the method isn't an actual hash so you can do something like `@red.get_listing()[:children].each` because it says `undefined method 'each'`. Need a way to convert to hash now

Comment: that's probably because get_listing is not returning a hash or if it does, it needs to have indifferent access. looking at your original hash, your hash keys are strings, so you access them using strings (if they don't have indifferent access)

Answer (score 1):

```
hash = {"modhash"=>"ubekfji9tr491ba98806d33ec78693dc157579335eb1ab283b", 
"children"=>[{"kind"=>"t3", "data"=>{"domain"=>"i.imgur.com", "banned_by"=>nil, "media_embed"=>{}, "subreddit"=>"pics", "selftext_html"=>nil, "selftext"=>"", "likes"=>nil, "link_flair_text"=>nil, "id"=>"1dt29e", "clicked"=>false, "title"=>"Our plumber in Italy put himself out there to ask us for help on his English homework :) Hope he passes his finals!", "media"=>nil, "score"=>3700, "approved_by"=>nil, "over_18"=>false, "hidden"=>false, "thumbnail"=>"http://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/Fdid4luCfXah0bQ7.jpg", "subreddit_id"=>"t5_2qh0u", "edited"=>false, "link_flair_css_class"=>nil, "author_flair_css_class"=>nil, "downs"=>17890, "saved"=>false, "is_self"=>false, "permalink"=>"/r/pics/comments/1dt29e/our_plumber_in_italy_put_himself_out_there_to_ask/", "name"=>"t3_1dt29e", "created"=>1367893951.0, "url"=>"http://i.imgur.com/3xn1c8s.jpg", "author_flair_text"=>nil, "author"=>"Junpha", "created_utc"=>1367865151.0, "distinguished"=>nil, "num_comments"=>553, "num_reports"=>nil, "ups"=>21590}},{"kind"=>"t3", "data"=>{"domain"=>"i.imgur.com", "banned_by"=>nil, "media_embed"=>{}, "subreddit"=>"funny", "selftext_html"=>nil, "selftext"=>"", "likes"=>nil, "link_flair_text"=>nil, "id"=>"1dt4xv", "clicked"=>false, "title"=>"What a beautiful, majestic.... oops", "media"=>nil, "score"=>2848, "approved_by"=>nil, "over_18"=>false, "hidden"=>false, "thumbnail"=>"http://a.thumbs.redditmedia.com/vkstE1PFr9iyYpux.jpg", "subreddit_id"=>"t5_2qh33", "edited"=>false, "link_flair_css_class"=>nil, "author_flair_css_class"=>nil, "downs"=>8128, "saved"=>false, "is_self"=>false, "permalink"=>"/r/funny/comments/1dt4xv/what_a_beautiful_majestic_oops/", "name"=>"t3_1dt4xv", "created"=>1367895955.0, "url"=>"http://i.imgur.com/62q1jWN.gif", "author_flair_text"=>nil, "author"=>"themisc", "created_utc"=>1367867155.0, "distinguished"=>nil, "num_comments"=>279, "num_reports"=>nil, "ups"=>10976}}
]}


hash['children'].map { |child| child['data']['url'] }
hash['children'].map { |child| child['data']['title'] }
```

or if you want to use symbols (and are in rails)

```
hash.with_indifferent_access[:children].first[:data][:title]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to *parse* them, just access its value:

```
hash[:data][:title]
hash[:data][:url]
```