# Ruby Accessing Deep Hashes

Tags: ruby, parsing, hash

So as an extension to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409008/ruby-parsing-hash). I found out the problem. The returned value *is* a hash but it's an extremely deep hash. So here's what the method prints:

> {"kind"=>"Listing",
>   "data"=>{"modhash"=>"5g8l2yr5ld67bcab9972a4fbf072381e422fea31c6ebf45cb5",
>   "children"=>[{"kind"=>"t3", "data"=>{"domain"=>"i.imgur.com",
>   "banned_by"=>nil, "media_embed"=>{}, "subreddit"=>"pics",
>   "selftext_html"=>nil, "selftext"=>"", "likes"=>nil,
>   "link_flair_text"=>nil, "id"=>"1dtlho", "clicked"=>false, "title"=>"It
>   almost looks like they're holding up a photograph", "media"=>nil,
>   "score"=>3866, "approved_by"=>nil, "over_18"=>false, "hidden"=>false,
>   "thumbnail"=>"http://f.thumbs.redditmedia.com/m2l6DYE1-gSVgpFk.jpg",
>   "subreddit_id"=>"t5_2qh0u", "edited"=>false,
>   "link_flair_css_class"=>nil, "author_flair_css_class"=>nil,
>   "downs"=>10684, "saved"=>false, "is_self"=>false,
>   "permalink"=>"/r/pics/comments/1dtlho/it_almost_looks_like_theyre_holding_up_a/", "name"=>"t3_1dtlho", "created"=>1367907910.0,
>   "url"=>"https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycMoe.jpg", "author_flair_text"=>nil,
>   "author"=>"kosen13", "created_utc"=>1367879110.0, "ups"=>14550,
>   "num_comments"=>308, "num_reports"=>nil, "distinguished"=>nil}},

So basically this is how I try to access it:

```
@reddit.get_listing().fetch('data',{}).fetch('children',{}).each do |child|
    puts child['data']
end
```

So that prints:

> {"domain"=>"i.imgur.com",
>   "banned_by"=>nil, "media_embed"=>{}, "subreddit"=>"pics",
>   "selftext_html"=>nil, "selftext"=>"", "likes"=>nil,
>   "link_flair_text"=>nil, "id"=>"1dtlho", "clicked"=>false, "title"=>"It
>   almost looks like they're holding up a photograph", "media"=>nil,
>   "score"=>3866, "approved_by"=>nil, "over_18"=>false, "hidden"=>false,
>   "thumbnail"=>"http://f.thumbs.redditmedia.com/m2l6DYE1-gSVgpFk.jpg",
>   "subreddit_id"=>"t5_2qh0u", "edited"=>false,
>   "link_flair_css_class"=>nil, "author_flair_css_class"=>nil,
>   "downs"=>10684, "saved"=>false, "is_self"=>false,
>   "permalink"=>"/r/pics/comments/1dtlho/it_almost_looks_like_theyre_holding_up_a/", "name"=>"t3_1dtlho", "created"=>1367907910.0,
>   "url"=>"https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycMoe.jpg", "author_flair_text"=>nil,
>   "author"=>"kosen13", "created_utc"=>1367879110.0, "ups"=>14550,
>   "num_comments"=>308, "num_reports"=>nil, "distinguished"=>nil}},

But now I need to access the domain and print titles so I tried something like this:

```
@reddit.get_listing().fetch('data',{}).fetch('children',{}).fetch('data', {}).each do |child|
    puts child['title']
end
```

But I get this error:
`:in 'fetch': can't convert String into Integer`

Any ideas how to get the last part of the hash?

Comment: I see your question has already been solved, but here's a tip anyway: Rather than chain all the fetch statements together, split it over multiple statements. That way, if it fails, the error message will point the line which actually causes the error. (It also makes the code more readable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `fetch` on an array. Try this:

```
@reddit.get_listing().fetch('data',{}).fetch('children',{}).each do |child|
    puts child['data']['title']
end
```

Comment: wow...i was so damn sure I tried this...i must have flipped data and title. This worked, thanks!